# Skrollr Background Animation Won't Swap

Tags: javascript, html, css, skrollr

Hi guys I was trying to swap the background of two images down the footer section of my website using skrollr.js (https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr). For some reason it won't scroll at all. I am trying to create a parallax site that has fixed position on the part below.

See image: http://prntscr.com/6yrckx

Here's the Markup of that part:

```
 <div id="starynight" 
                data-bottom-top="opacity: 1; background: !url(images/sunny.jpg); background-size: cover;"
                data--40-top="opacity: 0.5; background: !url(images/night.jpg); background-size: cover;"
                data--50-top="opacity: 0; background: !url(images/night.jpg); background-size: cover;"
                 data--60-top="opacity: 0.5; background: !url(images/night.jpg); background-size: cover;"
                data--70-top="opacity: 1; background: !url(images/night.jpg); background-size: cover;"
                >

                </div>
```

While here's the CSS:

```
#starynight{
    background: url('../images/sunny.jpg') no-repeat center;    
    width: 100%;
    height: 307px; 
    background-size: cover;

}


#road{
    background: url('../images/road.jpg') no-repeat center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 145px;
  background-size:cover;

}

#car{
   background: url('../images/car.png') no-repeat center;
  width: 325px;
  height: 125px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  left: 950px;
  top: 2100px;

}
```

My issue here is that when I scroll this part of my website it should swap the images of the sunny.jpg and night.jpg while the car is moving from right to left and also this background image must be fixed in position. For some reason my codes won't just work. Any idea what went wrong?

See my website here: http://goo.gl/aNOCiJ

Answer (score 0):

Animating backgrounds is not like animating positions or "number" data. You can't just transform one background into another by fading them (actually Firefox somehow can animate the transition, but lets not depend on that).

A solution to your problem is having 2 diferent divs for, 1 for your night scene, and other for your sunny sky just in the same position, one over the other and with the sunny one with a higher z-index.
Then what you need to animate on scroll is the opacity of the sunny sky, what makes the night scene appear.

Also I found that your level of scroll isn't enough to fade the opacity of the sunny sky completly, it ends in `0.603448`.

Hope it helps, please tell me if this worked.

Answer (score 0):

As stated already, background images can't be animated, only background colors. So you'll have to lay both images on top of each other and fade the top layer in like this -

*Untested

```css
#starynight-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; height: 307px;
}

#starynight-day {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background: url('images/sunny.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

#starynight-night {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background: url('images/night.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="starynight-wrap">
     <div id="starynight-day"></div>
     <div id="starynight-night"
         data-bottom-top="opacity: 0"
         data--50-top="opacity: 0;"
         data--60-top="opacity: 0.5;"
         data--70-top="opacity: 1;"
         >
    </div>
</div>
```